# What is this thing sticking out under the F-22 Raptor's fuselage?

Tags: aircraft-design, military, fighter, feature-identification, f-22

I was looking through some pictures I took of the [Lockheed Martin F-22 Raptor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lockheed_Martin_F-22_Raptor) performing a demo flight at [Oshkosh](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EAA_AirVenture_Oshkosh) 2023 and I noticed this thing sticking out from the bottom of the Raptor's fuselage. Could anyone please tell me what it is and what its function is?

[image: Circled in red]

Comment: As shown in the answers here: https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/82365/if-stealth-aircraft-are-invisible-to-radar-then-how-does-their-own-air-force-ma/82379#82379 , that is a Radar Reflector.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [If stealth aircraft are invisible to radar, then how does their own Air Force manage them or see them in flight?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/a/82379/64684)